# How to create an authentication middleware inside an AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm using AWS Cognito to authenticate my users, and once authenticated, they can call my API (API Gateway + Lambda). I'm doing all that using the Serverless Framework.

Once authenticated, when they call an endpoint that requires this authentication, my lambda will receive the user attributes through the `request.RequestContext.Authorizer["claims"]`. I had the idea of creating an authentication middleware to inject the current user into the context. But I'm certain that I'm doing something wrong (or can be improved).

How it works:

my-lambda.go:

```
package main

import (
    "context"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
    "github.com/company/api/middlewares"
)

func Handler(ctx context.Context, request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    fmt.Println(ctx.user)

    return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{}, nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(
        middlewares.Authentication(Handler),
    )
}
```

middlewares/authentication.go

```
package middlewares

import (
    "context"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/company/api/models"
)

func Authentication(next func(context.Context, events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error)) func(context.Context, events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    var user models.User

    return func(ctx context.Context, request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
        claims := request.RequestContext.Authorizer["claims"]

        // Find user by claims properties.
        if err := user.Current(claims); err != nil {
            return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{}, err
        }

        ctx.user = user
        return next(ctx, request)
    }
}
```

models/user.go:

```
package models

import (
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    "github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure"
)

type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    // Override ID cause we are using cognito.
    Email string `gorm:"primary_key,not null"`
    Site  Site
}

func (u *User) Current(claims interface{}) error {
    if err := mapstructure.Decode(claims, u); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if err := Database.Find(u).Error; err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

I have 2 questions:

- Is this the right way to define a function (Authentication function) that receives a function and returns another function? Because it is too verbose, I am feeling this is wrong.
- Is there a way to augment the `ctx` with an `user` attribute? The way that I'm trying, I see the error `ctx.user undefined (type context.Context has no field or method user)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st question about using the middleware:

There is certainly nothing wrong with the approach. Maybe the function will look a little better if you define the function type and use the defined name. `net/http` does the same thing with the `HandlerFunc`:

```
type HandlerFunc func(ResponseWriter, *Request)
```

Which will make the signature of a middleware more reasonable:

```
func AuthMiddleware(nextHop HandlerFunc) HandlerFunc
```

EDIT: doesn't the lambda library define such a type for the function signature? I would expect one to exist.

Also I don't know if the suffix `Middleware` makes sense in your case, but I think *some suffix* should make sense for you to give a little more context to the name of the function and make it more understandable. `AuthenticationMiddleware` could be an example.

EDIT: just saw the package name. LGTM really.

2nd question:

See [this](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#example_WithValue) for the correct use of `context`. There's also a common pitfal: `context.WithValue` returns a new context to use. Therefore you should not expect the passed parameter context to be mutated and should use the new one that is returned.